# The solution you've been looking for... (Find it, with these 11 simple steps!)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme

```
       1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 
     __________________________________
 1  |  T  N  R  C 18  P  1  2  L 19  Y
 2  | 14  E 25  A  D  D 10  Q  9  B  D
 3  | 20  2  R  V  5 12  C  7  3  P  T
 4  |  L  M 11  R 22  V  S  1  Y  3  C
 5  |  R  X  A  6  Z  8 22  G 10 15  I
 6  |  J  B  2 14  H 25  S  M  7  5 24
 7  |  5  F  8  O  5  K  N  8 12 18  U
 8  |  V 11  G  Q  4  Y 26  H  T  W  B
 9  | 13  I  4 17  R  U  A  J  P  8 21
10  |  S  E  E 20 16  E  O 23  5  3  L
11  |  O  4 19  X  9  N  D  1  R  6  H
```

> *First take the first of Roman numeral V,*
>   *Then second from second, it's easy you see.*
>   *Follow that up with the last of the second,*
>   *A Fourth: fifth of sixth, or so it is reckoned.*
>   *The next can be found in the middle of ten.*
>   *What's next? Third of three gets added on then.*
>   *Follow that pattern, append fourth of four,*
>   *Choose second of nine next, of this I am sure.*
>   *At ninth, we tack on the second of one,*
>   *And add on the third of eight (nearly done),*
>   *End with the start of second to last,*
>   *And join them together (I'm sure you'll be fast).*
>   *Now, follow these steps with an observant mind,*
>   *And all going well, ___ ________ you'll find!*

Comment: I liked this one because it has a lot of red herrings that most everyone would get at first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> RED HERRINGS

I dont think this answer needs much explanation.

**EDIT:**

Previous solution is wrong. True solution is:

> THE SOLUTION

How:

> **A** of **B** in each row of the poem refers to letter **A** of row **B** of the poem itself.

Comment: Hmmm... That doesn't seem right...

Comment: then there are way too many red herrings since even if you dont have the square you could still get "red herrings" as an answer just from the poem.

Comment: @Alconja edited my answer. Is this better?

Comment: Ahh, that looks better. Well done, you found the solution. :)

Comment: And for completeness, in case people stumble across this later, there's three lots of red herrings: indexing into the rows of the grid, indexing into the columns, and indexing into the phrases (I.e. First take the first of "**R**oman numeral V")

Comment: How actually refers to the second solution. The first (and wrong) one was simply done by getting the **A**'th letter of the **B**'th row in the top square.

Comment: Great puzzle @Alconja, but I think this answer could do with some more explanation. You've explained the real solution, but it might also be nice to explain how you found what you first thought was the solution.